# After swap Zoom

Tags: swap

Not working zoom after swap
After clicking on the additional image when zoomed displayed old image
what am I doing wrong
 Not working zoom after swap
After clicking on the additional image when zoomed displayed old image
what am I doing wrong
     ">

">" data-zoom-image="" title="" alt="" />">

" title=""> " title="" alt="" />

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    // Get main image info
    var img = $('#zoom_01').attr('src'); // get img popup href
    if (img != undefined) {
    var imgWidth = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, img.lastIndexOf('x'));
    var imgHeight = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf('x') + 1, img.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    $('.image-additional img').hover(function() {
    var newsrc = $(this).parent().attr('href');

    $('#zoom_01').attr({
    src: newsrc,
    title: $(this).attr('title'),
    alt: $(this).attr('alt'),
    width: imgWidth,
    height: imgHeight
    });

    $('#zoom_01').parent().attr('href', newsrc);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're asking. Firstly, repeating the same text does not get you answers quicker or better. Secondly, tell us what you're trying to do. Thirdly, tell us what actually happens. Fourthly, explain what steps you've taken to fix it. Fifthly, explain what happened when you tried those steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
  <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
    <li><div class="thumbnail" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><img id="zoom_01" src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" data-zoom-image="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></div></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($images) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
    <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"> <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```